# Oracle APEX | How to use Date Picker with time?

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I want to use `Date picker` control to set date and time as in this image:

[image]

I add `Date Picker` control to page but it is added without time tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the item attributes, under Appearance there is an attribute Format Mask.  If you set that to a value that includes time, the date picker will be rendered with the time component.

[image]